# How to pass multiple parameter in destructing structure in js ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of elements whom I am try to do total of few columns.

I have read about reduce method with destructuring the elements from it.
But problem is that I can't able to pass multiple params in it.

Plus it does not recognise the passed element in it.

**Here is my code:**

```
const prob = h.lead_plans.reduce((currentTotal, currentDau) => {
                                            console.log(currentDau.probability);
                                            return  ({'probability'} = {probability: ((currentTotal || 0) + currentDau.probability)})
                                        }, {probability: 0});
```

**Expected code:**

```
const prob = h.lead_plans.reduce((currentTotal, currentDau) => {
                                            return  ({probability,plan2} = {
                                                probability: ((currentTotal || 0) + currentDau.probability),
                                                plan2: ((currentTotal || 0) + currentDau.plan2),
                                            })
                                        }, {probability: 0, plan2: 0});
```

In return as a final result, I will be getting the sum of inner columns based on destructuring structure.

**Adding Hash:**

Here is my hash:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "leads": [
    {
        "id": 9,
        "branch": "Accounts",
        "classification": "Warm",
        "theme": "Lean",
        "branch_id": 3,
        "classification_id": 1,
        "project_id": 30,
        "theme_id": 3,
        "projectname": "project test",
        "comment": "commenters",
        "customername": "alex",
        "lead1id": 2,
        "lead1percent": "2.0",
        "lead2id": 2,
        "lead2percent": "2.0",
        "lead3id": 2,
        "lead3percent": "2.0",
        "lead_plans": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "lead_id": 9,
                "addcosts": "2.0",
                "fee": "2.0",
                "plan2": "2.0",
                "plan3": "2.0",
                "probability": "2.0",
                "year": "2020-02-12"
            }
        ],
        "offers": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "lead_id": 9,
                "addcosts": "2.0",
                "addcostsinfo": "some info",
                "days": "2020-02-12",
                "decision": "good",
                "decisiondate": "2020-02-12",
                "fee": "2.0",
                "mail": "mail goes here",
                "offerdate": "2020-02-12",
                "paper": "xyz"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "branch": "Accounts",
        "classification": "Warm",
        "theme": "Lean",
        "branch_id": 3,
        "classification_id": 1,
        "project_id": 28,
        "theme_id": 3,
        "projectname": "project test",
        "comment": "commenters",
        "customername": "alex",
        "lead1id": 2,
        "lead1percent": "2.0",
        "lead2id": 2,
        "lead2percent": "2.0",
        "lead3id": 2,
        "lead3percent": "2.0",
        "lead_plans": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "lead_id": 10,
                "addcosts": "2.0",
                "fee": "2.0",
                "plan2": "2.0",
                "plan3": "2.0",
                "probability": "2.0",
                "year": "2020-02-12"
            }
        ],
        "offers": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "lead_id": 10,
                "addcosts": "2.0",
                "addcostsinfo": "some info",
                "days": "2020-02-12",
                "decision": "good",
                "decisiondate": "2020-02-12",
                "fee": "2.0",
                "mail": "mail goes here",
                "offerdate": "2020-02-12",
                "paper": "xyz"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "branch": "Accounts",
        "classification": "Warm",
        "theme": "Lean",
        "branch_id": 3,
        "classification_id": 1,
        "project_id": 30,
        "theme_id": 3,
        "projectname": "project test",
        "comment": "commenters",
        "customername": "alex",
        "lead1id": 2,
        "lead1percent": "2.0",
        "lead2id": 2,
        "lead2percent": "2.0",
        "lead3id": 2,
        "lead3percent": "2.0",
        "lead_plans": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "lead_id": 11,
                "addcosts": "2.0",
                "fee": "2.0",
                "plan2": "2.0",
                "plan3": "2.0",
                "probability": "2.0",
                "year": "2020-02-12"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "lead_id": 11,
                "addcosts": "6.0",
                "fee": "5.0",
                "plan2": "4.0",
                "plan3": "3.0",
                "probability": "6.0",
                "year": "2020-02-12"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "lead_id": 11,
                "addcosts": "5.0",
                "fee": "2.0",
                "plan2": "5.0",
                "plan3": "1.0",
                "probability": "3.0",
                "year": "2020-02-12"
            }
        ],
        "offers": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "lead_id": 11,
                "addcosts": "2.0",
                "addcostsinfo": "some info",
                "days": "2020-02-12",
                "decision": "good",
                "decisiondate": "2020-02-12",
                "fee": "2.0",
                "mail": "mail goes here",
                "offerdate": "2020-02-12",
                "paper": "xyz"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "lead_id": 11,
                "addcosts": "7.0",
                "addcostsinfo": "some info",
                "days": "2020-02-12",
                "decision": "good",
                "decisiondate": "2020-02-12",
                "fee": "9.0",
                "mail": "mail goes here",
                "offerdate": "2020-02-12",
                "paper": "xyz"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "lead_id": 11,
                "addcosts": "8.0",
                "addcostsinfo": "some info",
                "days": "2020-02-12",
                "decision": "good",
                "decisiondate": "2020-02-12",
                "fee": "7.0",
                "mail": "mail goes here",
                "offerdate": "2020-02-12",
                "paper": "xyzas"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "branch": "Accounts",
        "classification": "Warm",
        "theme": "Lean",
        "branch_id": 3,
        "classification_id": 1,
        "project_id": 30,
        "theme_id": 3,
        "projectname": "project test",
        "comment": "commenters",
        "customername": "alex",
        "lead1id": 2,
        "lead1percent": "2.0",
        "lead2id": 2,
        "lead2percent": "2.0",
        "lead3id": 2,
        "lead3percent": "2.0",
        "lead_plans": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "lead_id": 11,
                "addcosts": "2.0",
                "fee": "2.0",
                "plan2": "2.0",
                "plan3": "2.0",
                "probability": "2.0",
                "year": "2020-02-12"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "lead_id": 11,
                "addcosts": "6.0",
                "fee": "5.0",
                "plan2": "4.0",
                "plan3": "3.0",
                "probability": "6.0",
                "year": "2020-02-12"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "lead_id": 11,
                "addcosts": "5.0",
                "fee": "2.0",
                "plan2": "5.0",
                "plan3": "1.0",
                "probability": "3.0",
                "year": "2020-02-12"
            }
        ],
        "offers": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "lead_id": 11,
                "addcosts": "2.0",
                "addcostsinfo": "some info",
                "days": "2020-02-12",
                "decision": "good",
                "decisiondate": "2020-02-12",
                "fee": "2.0",
                "mail": "mail goes here",
                "offerdate": "2020-02-12",
                "paper": "xyz"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "lead_id": 11,
                "addcosts": "7.0",
                "addcostsinfo": "some info",
                "days": "2020-02-12",
                "decision": "good",
                "decisiondate": "2020-02-12",
                "fee": "9.0",
                "mail": "mail goes here",
                "offerdate": "2020-02-12",
                "paper": "xyz"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "lead_id": 11,
                "addcosts": "8.0",
                "addcostsinfo": "some info",
                "days": "2020-02-12",
                "decision": "good",
                "decisiondate": "2020-02-12",
                "fee": "7.0",
                "mail": "mail goes here",
                "offerdate": "2020-02-12",
                "paper": "xyzas"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "branch": "Accounts",
        "classification": "Warm",
        "theme": "Lean",
        "branch_id": 3,
        "classification_id": 1,
        "project_id": 30,
        "theme_id": 3,
        "projectname": "project test",
        "comment": "commenters",
        "customername": "alex",
        "lead1id": 2,
        "lead1percent": "2.0",
        "lead2id": 2,
        "lead2percent": "2.0",
        "lead3id": 2,
        "lead3percent": "2.0",
        "lead_plans": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "lead_id": 11,
                "addcosts": "2.0",
                "fee": "2.0",
                "plan2": "2.0",
                "plan3": "2.0",
                "probability": "2.0",
                "year": "2020-02-12"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "lead_id": 11,
                "addcosts": "6.0",
                "fee": "5.0",
                "plan2": "4.0",
                "plan3": "3.0",
                "probability": "6.0",
                "year": "2020-02-12"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "lead_id": 11,
                "addcosts": "5.0",
                "fee": "2.0",
                "plan2": "5.0",
                "plan3": "1.0",
                "probability": "3.0",
                "year": "2020-02-12"
            }
        ],
        "offers": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "lead_id": 11,
                "addcosts": "2.0",
                "addcostsinfo": "some info",
                "days": "2020-02-12",
                "decision": "good",
                "decisiondate": "2020-02-12",
                "fee": "2.0",
                "mail": "mail goes here",
                "offerdate": "2020-02-12",
                "paper": "xyz"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "lead_id": 11,
                "addcosts": "7.0",
                "addcostsinfo": "some info",
                "days": "2020-02-12",
                "decision": "good",
                "decisiondate": "2020-02-12",
                "fee": "9.0",
                "mail": "mail goes here",
                "offerdate": "2020-02-12",
                "paper": "xyz"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "lead_id": 11,
                "addcosts": "8.0",
                "addcostsinfo": "some info",
                "days": "2020-02-12",
                "decision": "good",
                "decisiondate": "2020-02-12",
                "fee": "7.0",
                "mail": "mail goes here",
                "offerdate": "2020-02-12",
                "paper": "xyzas"
            }
        ]
    }
],
    "message": "Projects fetched successfully"
}
```

Currently, its working for me but I am forced to write 3 codes for one job.

**Working code:**

```
const probability = h.lead_plans.reduce((currentTotal, currentDau) => parseFloat((currentTotal || 0)) + parseFloat(currentDau.probability), 0)
const plan2 = h.lead_plans.reduce((currentTotal, currentDau) => parseFloat((currentTotal || 0)) + parseFloat(currentDau.plan2), 0)
const plan3 = h.lead_plans.reduce((currentTotal, currentDau) => parseFloat((currentTotal || 0)) + parseFloat(currentDau.plan3), 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how the code would work. The `currentTotal` value on the first run through is the second argument to the reduce function [`Array#reduce(function,initialValue)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) which is `{probability: 0, plan2: 0}` rather than a number.

So, you don't need to do any object destructuring, you just need to use the accumulator to sum the individual keys of the object you want, and then return those new values. Then your end result will be of the same type that you used for the initialValue.

This casts the probability and plan2 values to numbers so they'll be able to properly be summed.

```js
const h = {
  lead_plans: [{
    probability: '2.2',
    plan2: '5.2'
  }, {
    probability: '7.8',
    plan2: '3.1'
  }, {
    probability: '1.8',
    plan2: '2.3'
  }]
}
const result = h.lead_plans.reduce(
  (accumulator, currentDau) => {
    return {
      probability: accumulator.probability + parseFloat((currentDau.probability || 0)),
      plan2: accumulator.plan2 + parseFloat((currentDau.plan2 || 0)),
    };
  }, {
    probability: 0,
    plan2: 0
  }
);
console.log(result);
```

Here's an example of how to make a more re-usable reducer for summing all entries in an object:

Note, this is casting all keys to numbers, so they'll be NaN if there is a value that isn't a number.

```js
const h = {
  lead_plans: [{
    probability: '2.5',
    plan2: 5
  }, {
    probability: 7,
    plan2: 3
  }, {
    probability: 1,
    plan2: 2
  }]
}
const reducerSumAll = (accumulator, object) => {
  // Ensure there are no accidental mutations
  const current = { ...accumulator };
  for (const key of Object.keys(object)) {
    // Make sure we are only accumulating the number types.
    current[key] = parseFloat(current[key]||0) + parseFloat(object[key]||0);
  }
  return current;
};
const result = h.lead_plans.reduce(reducerSumAll)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Could you please explain the new revision in your answer? I will learn new thing from it.

Comment: I was modifying it further and just used parseFloat, but you can use +variable to cast a the variable to a number.